# Как правильно делать подгрузку информации?

Tags: php, html, ajax, база-данных, оптимизация

Как правильно делать подгрузку информации например на случай чата, чтобы ежесекундно было обращение к БД за новыми сообщениями или ещё например "кто онлайн"? Под словом "правильно", я имею ввиду, чтобы минимальная нагрузка на сайт была, я думаю может при помощи ajax вызывать php скрипт который обращается к бд и делает что там хочет, но я не знаю правильно ли так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если по самым последним веяниям, то на это применяются [WebSockets](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). Постоянное соединение, по которому сам сервер может передавать обновления, когда у него что-то меняется, не тратясь на новые соединения, HTTP заголовки и тому подобное. А при разрыве или первом входе синхронизируется текущее состояние.

Если нет websockets, применяется long polling. Если и оно не подходит - увы, клиент должен запрашивать периодически.

Comment: А как сокет соединение реализовать на сайте? В программах на компьютере я без проблем делаю сокет соединения, а вот на сайте я не знаю к сожалению :(

Comment: А вот это уже должен поддерживать движок сайта. Не зная, какой движок, никто вам не скажет, что от него нужно - банально версию новую взять, плагин готовый или серьёзно что-то писать.

Comment: А если движка нету, сайт с нуля :D

Comment: В первую очередь должен хостинг поддерживать, а дальше уже можно к любому движку что угодно накостылять